# How to switch between images in interactive way in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: html, image, jupyter-notebook, markdown, python-interactive

If I write the following in my Jupyter Notebook Markdown cell, I get to see an image saved in my "`Images`" folder

```
<img src="Images/T1.png">
```

However, I want to switch between 3 images, `T1.png`, `T2.png` and `T3.png` saved in my `Images` folder interactively by putting some line of code in markdown cell. Can anyone help me do that using Jupyter Notebook markdown cell? I was trying this (that I found on stackoverflow)

```
<input type="radio" name="T1" class="radio1" checked/>
<input type="radio" name="T2" class="radio2" />
<input type="radio" name="T3" class="radio3" />


<div class="image1">
  <img src="Images/T1.png">
</div>
<div class="image2">
  <img src="Images/T2.png">
</div>
<div class="image3">
  <img src="Images/T3.png">
</div>
```

But I am getting all the images stacked one after another like this (I want them one at a time on screen):
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some javascript/css, which is not supported by a `Markdown` cell. Instead just display an HTML document in python. Here you have:

```py
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML

html = """
    Select an Image:
    <input type="radio" name="images" onclick="show1();" checked>Image 1</input>
    <input type="radio" name="images" onclick="show2();">Image 2</input>
    <input type="radio" name="images" onclick="show3();">Image 3</input>


    <div id="image1">
      <img src="Images/T1.png">
    </div>
    <div id="image2">
      <img src="Images/T2.png">
    </div>
    <div id="image3">
      <img src="Images/T3.png">
    </div>
    
    <script>
    function show1(){
      document.getElementById('image1').style.display ='block';
      document.getElementById('image2').style.display ='none';
      document.getElementById('image3').style.display ='none';
    }
    function show2(){
      document.getElementById('image2').style.display ='block';
      document.getElementById('image1').style.display ='none';
      document.getElementById('image3').style.display ='none';
    }
    function show3(){
      document.getElementById('image3').style.display ='block';
      document.getElementById('image1').style.display ='none';
      document.getElementById('image2').style.display ='none';
    }
    show1()
    </script>
"""
display(HTML(html))
```

[image]